# Twitter Bootstrap: Reload page does not work when modal is hidden

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a table where the last tag "td" got a call to a modal window. The problem is that only works for first modal window when it is hidden the page reloads, but for the other modal windows reload does not work.

```
<a class="icon-remove-sign" id="exclusao" href="#modalExclude{{janela.campanha.id}}" data-toggle="modal" title="Excluir"></a> 
// this generate the following urls:
// http://localhost:8000/display/detail/15/#modalExclude11
// http://localhost:8000/display/detail/15/#modalExclude12
// http://localhost:8000/display/detail/15/#modalExclude13
```

The JQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#exclusao').click(function() {
        var modal = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log(modal); // show the href only for the first row --> #modalExclude11
        // show modal
        $(modal).modal({
            show: false,
        });
        // clean message info in modal
        $('div#messageExclude').html('');
        // reload page when modal is hidden
        $(modal).on('hidden', function() {
            window.location.reload(true) // work only for the first row --> #modalExclude11
        });

    });
});
```

All modals are shown correctly, but only makes the page reload to the first row of the table. Does anyone know what can be?
Thanks!

Comment: Ugh, why do you prefix your variables with `$`, especially those that do not contain jQuery objects?

Comment: Can you post the js code that is generating your urls? I suspect that since it only works for the first one, the call is generating the urls again and not picking up the current one...

Comment: I remove the "$" from the code.
The image show two rows, work only for the first row: http://i.imgur.com/z7bJI.png

Comment: I find your question a bit to abstract, can you post a link to working example?

Comment: I have a table, and in td i have a modal, every row have a modal window. The problem is the reload work only for the first modal row.
#modalExclude11 is my fisrt modal, and reload works. But starting from #modalExclude12 the reload not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem are the ID in:

```
<a class="icon-remove-sign" id="exclusao" href="#modalExclude{{janela.campanha.id}}" data-toggle="modal" title="Excluir"></a>
```

Need work with CLASS, I forgeted that the ID must be unique in code, but with class is working.

```
class="icon-remove-sign"
```

Thanks!